# How to merge multiple regex into one in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, regex, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to remove whitespaces from a column in a Postgres table.
I am using SQLAlchemy to do it.

e.g. `'   some  value  '` should become `'some value'`.

My code is:

```
sqlalchemy.func.regexp_replace(
                # replace whitespaces with a single space
                sqlalchemy.func.regexp_replace(source_column_instance, ' {2,}', ' ', 'g'),
                # also remove leading and trailing whitespaces
                '^ | $', '', 'g')
```

The above is working fine but I want to merge the two regexes into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sqlalchemy.func.regexp_replace(source_column_instance, '^ +| +$|( ){2,}', '\\1', 'g')
```

Here,

- `^ +` - matches 1  or more spaces at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `+$`- matches 1  or more spaces at the end of the string
- `|` - or
- `( ){2,}` - matches and captures a single space into Group 1 two or more times.

The replacement is `\1`, backreference to Group 1 value, so that only one space is kept in the result where there were two or more spaces.

Comment: it actually works. Thanks a lot. However, it will take me few more minutes to understand the backreference as I have seen it the first time today

Comment: @HarisMuzaffar See [Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)

Comment: Hey, it doesn't work if i have more than one leading space. Can you test that?

Comment: @HarisMuzaffar Did you use `'^ +| +$|( ){2,}'`?

Comment: this one works, the first one i.e. '^ | $|( ){2,}' seems to be not working. May be you should try to modify '^ | $|( ){2,}' or remove it from your answer